# Clarification on a question about $C_b(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, separable-spaces

Hello I've been given the following question and I'm a bit confused.

> Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on X a metric space. Prove that the bounded continuous functions are separable in $L^p(\mu)$.

Now does this question only want us to consider continuous bounded functions that lie in $L^p(\mu)$ and use the $L^p$ measure, in which case I have a solution since simple functions are dense in $L^p$. However I'm not sure if the question intends for me to look at the space of continuous bounded functions including the functions that do not lie in $L^p$ and show that it is separable under the $L^P$ norm.

In the latter case I am unable to find either a proof or a counterexample.

Many Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you want to consider a finite Borel measure? In that case all bounded (continuous) functions lie in $L^p$.

Comment: I am not sure what the second interpretation is. If a function $f$ is not in $L^p$ then $\Vert f \Vert_p$ is not a well-defined expression.

Comment: I know that in this question the measure need not be finite. Also what I mean by the second part is that even though $||f||_p$ may not be well defined maybe the difference between $f$ and some element in the dense countable subset is finite in the $L^p$ norm.

Comment: Update! turns out you were correct! There was a mistake in the lecture notes and the indeed the measure should be a finite Borel measure. Thanks!